# External XMPP component - Anyone know a Tutorial or Open Source Example please?

Tags: java, xmpp, whack

I want to run an XMPP server ([Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)) and register an external component to handle the messages it will recieve (using the [Whack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/whack/index.jsp) library). The external component will run my game logic and I will be using XMPP to send player moves to the server and status updates in the other direction. The bonus with XMPP is that we get built in chat for free.

The trouble is, although Ignite look fairly established, I can't find a tutorial on how to write, register and debug an External XMPP component written with Whack, there are very few in general for that matter.

I am not invested in either the server implementation or the External Component library, java is just my language of choice. If I was to move to Erlang or Scala or something it would have to be a very simple in that language.

A single tutorial or example would go a long way here, I just need an basic External XMPP component pretty please!

Kind regards,

Gavin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few examples/tutorials for related XMPP libraries like [Tinder](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/docs/DOC-1924) and [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/) which you may find useful.

Or, in a rather different vein, you could decide to be protocol-agnostic and use [IMified's API](http://www.imified.com/developers/api), in which they host the "chatbot" (as it were) which connects with your simple HTTP-based response server built in whatever language/framework/whatever you prefer. ([They do a lot better explaining it than I do.](http://www.imified.com/))

Answer (score 4):

I found this [tutorial](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/docs/DOC-1924) which explains how an external component can be implemented using the Whack library.